# Using AWS lambda to run query on Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have a very simple table on AWSAthena with three column: name, city and price. I can run the following simple query:

```
select * from mytestdb.test where city='austin'
```

and the running time is less than 1 second. I create a lambda function using boto3 to run the same query however the query can not be finished after 3 mins

```
import time
import boto3

# athena constant
DATABASE = 'mytestdb'
TABLE = 'test'
# S3 constant
output='s3://mybucket'


COLUMN = 'city'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # get keyword
    keyword = 'Austin'
    # created query
    query = "SELECT * FROM %s.%s where %s = '%s';" % (DATABASE, TABLE, COLUMN, keyword)
    # athena client
    client = boto3.client('athena')


    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output,
        }
    )

    # get query execution id
    query_execution_id = response['QueryExecutionId']
    print(query_execution_id)

    # get execution status


    # get query execution

    query_status = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
    print('Amir2')
    query_execution_status = query_status['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']


    time.sleep(200)        

    if query_execution_status == 'SUCCEEDED':
        result = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
    else:
        print('killed')
        client.stop_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)

    return
```

the table has total 10 rows so it is not large at all. Is the right way to lookup for the desirable value based on city or there is better way to do that?

**UPDATE:** here is my lambda permission (It has full access to athena and s3:

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1547414166585",
      "Action": [
        "athena:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1547414166586",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*"
    }    ] }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the query has _never_ successfully executed? Or does it _sometimes_ take 3 minutes and then timeout?

Comment: I just limit the running time to 3 mins because if it takes more than 3 it will not work for me.

Comment: Are you saying that the query has _never_ successfully executed? If so, it would appear that there is something wrong with the code, rather than Lambda/Athena. If you run the code locally (outside of Lambda), does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works locally

Comment: Have you checked the IAM permissions the Lambda has? Specifically for Athena and S3? On local, you might be using your own secret/access keys.

EDIT: Also your keyword has city name "Austin" - A in caps. The query in the first line has "austin" - a in lowercase. Please verify this as well.

Might want to reduce that sleep (200) or increase the lambda execution time. Now it can run for 15 mins.

Comment: Your `time.sleep(200)` command will wait **200 seconds**, which is over 3 minutes. You should instead create a `while` loop, and perhaps sleep 3 seconds each time.

Comment: @Abi add the lambda permission to the question. it has full permission for S3 and Athena. I also modify the city name and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

A little late here but make sure the Role for your lambda has the correct policies.

I solved it by giving full access to not only Athena but also Glue which you may be missing. Add those policies to your lambda role.